# How to show an image when Chrome is offline

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to show an image when the Chrome browser is offline, and when it's online show the webpage.

I transferred the image to base64 data and tried to load it in the img tag, however the base64 data is too large.

Is there a way to show an image when the browser is offline?

```
import imageToBase64 from "image-to-base64";

const Home = () => {

  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(true);

  // Checks to see if the browser has internet connection or not
  window.addEventListener("online", () => setIsOnline(true));
  window.addEventListener("offline", () => setIsOnline(false));

 //Link to the image 
 const idleImgUrl = `${window.location.href}${coffeeMachine}`;

//convert image to base64 and save to local storage
  imageToBase64(idleImgUrl)
    .then(res => {
      window.localStorage.setItem("idleImgData", res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  return (
    isOnline 
    ? (<div>The web page to show</div>) 
    :

    // <p> tag shows 
    <p>The browser is offline now</p> 
    // img tag does not show
    (<img src={window.localStorage.getItem("idleImgData"} />)
   );
};
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: If you are offline, you might not even be able to load your react bundle.js file though.. Also, why keeping in localStorage? If the user was able to load your bundle, you can just store the b64 hardcoded as a variable or make your very first ajax call from your app to load the image and keep it in your state.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to load the image while the user agent still has an internet connection. The image won't be downloaded until you render the `<img>` tag. The cached image can then be displayed without issue later.

I wrote a short `create-react-app` example to illustrate.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [online, setOnline] = useState(true);

  const onlineListener = useCallback(() => setOnline(true), [setOnline]);
  const offlineListener = useCallback(() => setOnline(false), [setOnline]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('online', onlineListener);
    window.addEventListener('offline', offlineListener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', onlineListener);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', offlineListener);
    };
  }, [onlineListener, offlineListener]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img
        style={online ? { display: 'none' } : undefined}
        src="TODO"
        alt="no internet"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

It displays an image when the user agent loses connection and hides it again when connection is restored. It obviously won't work if connection is cut to begin with, but in such a case how did the user load your application ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are offline, you might not even be able to load your react bundle.js file in the first place and there is nothing you can do about it.

Also, I don't see the advantage of keeping it in your localStorage in this case. Browsers are probably going to cache it anyway, if size matters here.

If the user was able to load your bundle, you can just store the b64 hardcoded as a variable directly in your bundle or initiate an ajax on componentDidMount (using useEffect since you use hooks).

```js
const Home = () => {
  const [base64Img, setBase64Img] = useState();
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(true);

  const setOnline = () => setIsOnline(true);
  const setOffline = () => setIsOnline(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    initiateB64Retrieval().then((b64) => setBase64Img(b64));

    window.addEventListener('online', setOnline);
    window.addEventListener('offline', setOffline);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', setOnline);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', setOffline);
    }
  }, [])

  ...
}
```

Always good practice to remove your event listeners. Note that you cannot remove event listeners if passed with anonymous functions or when using .bind() as it creates another reference for the function.